# Sum with conditions in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to write a query using Snowflake where I want to sum the total payment of a user who have multiple accounts (one email can create multiple accounts, yes).

If at least one account is currently active, then I want to sum up the total paid money(all payment history for that user), whether the account is active or not.

Columns I'm using:

```
CustomerEmail
Active
Total_Paid
```

Comment: without a db schema it will be difficult to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select customeremail, sum(total_paid)
from test
where customeremail IN (select customeremail from test where active =true )
group by customeremail;
```

Comment: Isn't this will only sum up the total paid of active accounts only? 
Maybe I wasn't clear in my question, if at least one account is active then I want to sum up the total paid amont that been done useing 
that email for all its account (the active and non active accounts)... if the user has no account active then will skip it

Comment: No, it will not. It will sum the total paid for all customers who have at least one active account. Can you try to run it in your environment?

Answer (score 1):

Using HAVING and [COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html):

```
SELECT customeremail, SUM(total_paid) AS total
FROM test
GROUP BY customeremail
HAVING COUNT_IF(active) > 0;
```